# how to free resources allocated by XopenDisplay

Tags: c++, xlib

I have a following code

```
bool isValidDisplay() {
   if (!XOpenDisplay(NULL)) {
      return false;
   }
   return true;    
 }
```

As I understand XOpenDisplay  is allocating resources, what is correct way to free the resources in the above code .Does calling XCloseDisplay will solve the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, calling XCloseDisplay frees the result of a successful XOpenDisplay.

I'm guessing this is what you want, to free resources immediately.

```
bool isValidDisplay() {
   Display *d;
   if (!(d = XOpenDisplay(NULL))) {
      return false;
   }
   XCloseDisplay(d);
   return true;    
 }
```

Source:

```
$ man XOpenDisplay
```

Comment: i was just having a conversation today about deallocating dynamically allocated memory. its interesting to see it in practice in a library function like this. what library are we talking about here? thanks!

Comment: @lopezdp: The library known as X.

Comment: The library is Xlib, not X. The latter is the protocol.

Comment: *shrug* I'm pretty sure back in the day I linked to it with -lX.